# UpdatePanel in a ASP.NET AJAX Server Control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, web-controls

Creating an ASP.NET AJAX Server Control. Overriding the RenderContents method, I placed in this code shown below:

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    var updatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
    updatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
    updatePanel.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.AutoID;
    updatePanel.ID = "CaptchaUpdatePanel";
    updatePanel.ChildrenAsTriggers = true;

    //var placeHolder = new PlaceHolder();
    var hiddenField = new HiddenField();
    hiddenField.ID = "captchaKey";
    updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(hiddenField);

    var panel = new Panel();
    panel.ID = "Captcha";
    var imgButton = new ImageButton();
    imgButton.ID = "RefreshCaptcha";
    imgButton.TabIndex = 0;
    imgButton.AlternateText = "Refresh Captcha Characters";
    imgButton.ImageUrl = RefreshButtonPath;
    imgButton.Width = 36;
    imgButton.Height = 36;
    panel.Controls.Add(imgButton);

    updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(panel);

    AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
    trigger.ControlID = "CaptchaRefresh";
    trigger.EventName = "Click";
    updatePanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);

    updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.RenderControl(writer);

    base.RenderContents(writer);
}
```

Compiling the Control and dropping it onto a Web Forms page, I find that the UpdatePanel doen't work. The button inside the UpdatePanel, when clicked, performs a complete postback not asynchronously.

Without success, I have been searching the web for an answer.

I'm wondering if it is a good idea to have an UpdatePanel within a AJAX Server Control. I have been successful performing this similer task using a UserControl.

HTML Script is below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CaptchaControl" Namespace="CaptchaControlx" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script runat="server">

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    </script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    <cc1:captcha runat="server" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UpdatePanel` needs to be added in `servercontrol` at [`CreateChildControls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx) function. So that it can be registered to `ScriptManager` as a updatepanel. While rendering it in `RenderContents` function, result in just html of UpdatePanel to be added in ServerControl.

Comment: I eliminated the RenderContents function and created all controls within CreateChildControls. Why do most Server Control examples show contols being created wihtin RenderContents, when CreateChildControls work? Any advantages? Works great, thank you.

Comment: RenderContents function have it advantages like it can skip control been stored in "ViewState", control's Html can be controlled directly.